# Add a Free product to woocommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce

I have a snippet that adds a free product to woocommerce cart depending on selected variations. The code is working fine but the problem is when I reload  the page, the quantity increases. I need to know how to check when the cart is updated or something to prevent add several times the free product.

this is the snippet.

```html
  if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
       global $product,$post;
       $added=false;
       $i=1;
       $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
       $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
       $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
       $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
       $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
       $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
       foreach ($terms as $term) {
             $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
             if($product_cat_id==65){
               if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 2",0) !== false ){      
                     WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748);
                     $added=true;
               }else if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 4",0) !== false ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748,2);
                     $added=true;
               }else if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 6",0) !== false ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748,3);
                    $added=true;
               }else if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 8",0) !== false ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748,4);
                    $added=true;
               }else if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 10",0) !== false ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748,5);
                    $added=true;
               }else if(strpos($variation->get_formatted_name(),"Dinner for 12",0) !== false ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart(104748,6);
                    $added=true;
               }
            }
       }
  }
}
```

Apreciate any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check everytime whether your product already exist in cart or not. If not then only add the product to your cart, else you need to skip.

Please use this function to add your product to cart -

```
function add_in_cart($product_id) { 
    global $woocommerce;
    var $isProductExist = false;

    foreach( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) { 
        $_product = $val['data']; 
        if($product_id == $_product->id ) { 
        $isProductExist =true;
        break;
    } 
    if($isProductExist=false)
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
}
```